# Get second tweet using twitter fetcher

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm using Twitter fetcher by Jason Mayes (http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/) to show tweets on a website. Now I want to get only the second tweet that has got a certain hashtag, not the first AND the second, just the second.

Are there an easy way to accomplish this?

So far I'm using this to get the first tweet. How can I change that to get the second?

```
var config2 = {
  "id": '<-- there's an id here -->',
  "domId": 'hashtageightyfive',
  "maxTweets": 1,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "showInteraction": true,
  "showRetweet": false
 };
twitterFetcher.fetch(config2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not grab two tweets and then hide the first one with js/css. This would depend on your tweet markup but something like this should work:

**JS**

```
var config2 = {
  "id": '<-- there's an id here -->',
  "domId": 'hashtageightyfive',
  "maxTweets": 2,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "showInteraction": true,
  "showRetweet": false
 };
twitterFetcher.fetch(config2);
```

**CSS**

```
#twitter-feed li:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: The tweet gets loaded into a tweetWrapper div (#hashtageightyfive), and only the first div shows up there. So I need to solve this within the js.

Comment: But if you change `maxTweets` to 2 then you will load the last 2 tweets with that hashtag, then hide the first?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick. Simply replace the ID with your Twitter Widget ID, and in the custom function at the end, where we use getElementById, replace that id with the ID of the element you wish to inject the tweet into. This only injects 1 tweet into the DOM which is better for performance too as you wont have wasted DOM creation which is then hidden using the CSS hide solution above.

```
var config = {
  "id": 'YOUR_TWITTER_WIDGET_ID_HERE',
  "domId": '',
  "maxTweets": 2,
  "enableLinks": true,
  "showInteraction": true,
  "showRetweet": false,
  "customCallback": handleTweets
};

function handleTweets(tweets){
    var n = tweets.length - 1;
    var element = document.getElementById('YOUR_DOM_ID_HERE');
    element.innerHTML = tweets[n] ;
}
```